# error when using dfSummary in summarytools

Tags: r, r-markdown, summarytools

I am using `summarytools` in `rmarkdown` and I followed the instructions to print a summary statistics table, but it would not work:

```
dfSummary(tobacco, plain.ascii = FALSE, style = "grid", 
          graph.magnif = 0.75, valid.col = FALSE, tmp.img.dir = "/tmp")
```

I get an error:

```
Error in magick_image_write, RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG
```

Is there a way to get around the error? I checked and `magick` is installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

could you provide more info on your system?

Until this is resolved, what you could do is go back to an earlier version of summarytools, for instance:

`devtools::install_github("dcomtois/summarytools", ref = "0.8.9")`

If you want, you can open an issue on the [project page on GitHub](https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools/issues) and we can look into this in more depth.